# ASP.NET MVC4 StructureMap ExceptionCode202

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, structuremap

I'm in the process of converting an ASP.NET MVC3 (LinqToSQL, EntityFramework) project to MVC4. I've created a fresh MVC4 project in VS2012, added packages, copied my Views, Controllers, etc.

Most things seem to work fine except when I try to access a controller that makes use of a Respository, as follows:

```
public class CustomerController : Controller
{
    private ICustomerRepository _cr;

    public CustomerController()
    {
        this._cr = new CustomerRepository(TTDataProvider.DB);
    }

    public CustomerController(ICustomerRepository customerRepository)
    {
        this._cr = customerRepository;
    }
```

if I'm in VS2012 and debugging, what I'll get is an exception: "Activation error occured while trying to get instance of type CustomerController, key """. The exception is of type Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.Activation and the Inner Exception is: "StructureMap Exception Code:  202\nNo Default Instance defined for PluginFamily TTLW.Models.TTLWDataContext, TTLW, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"}.

My IoC code is:

```
using StructureMap;
using FluentSecurity;
using System.Diagnostics;
namespace TTLW {
    public static class IoC {
        public static IContainer Initialize() {
            ObjectFactory.Initialize(x =>
                        {
                            x.Scan(scan =>
                                    {
                                        scan.TheCallingAssembly();
                                        scan.WithDefaultConventions();
                                        scan.AddAllTypesOf<IPolicyViolationHandler>();
                                    });
                        });
            return ObjectFactory.Container;
        }
    }
}
```

And here's StructureMapMVC.cs

```
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using StructureMap;
using TTLW.DependencyResolution;

[assembly: WebActivator.PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(TTLW.App_Start.StructuremapMvc), "Start")]

namespace TTLW.App_Start {
    public static class StructuremapMvc {
        public static void Start() {
            IContainer container = IoC.Initialize();
            DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new StructureMapDependencyResolver(container));
            GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = DependencyResolver.Current.ToServiceResolver();
        }
    }
}
```

As I say, this was all working without problems in my MVC3 application (although I was of course using the MVC3 version of StructureMap).

Once I hit the exception, if I just choose to continue then everything works (i.e. the controller functions); this is confirmed by choosing "Start Without Debugging" instead of "Debug". When I do that there is no exception thrown and things work as designed.

I've searched and come across posts from Phil Haack, Brett Allred and others (in fact I've already incorporated Allred's code in the last line of StructureMapMVC) but haven't found a solution. I can't consider the project converted as long as this exception is staring me in the face.

I've included all the code and messages I think are reasonable and would appreciate any insights. If you need to see more just let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you seen this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2910493/structuremap-exception-code-202-no-default-instance-defined-for-pluginfamily

Comment: No, that's one my searches didn't dig up. I'm irked by the fact I had no problems in MVC3, but I'll study the post and hopefully I'll learn something. Thanks much.

Comment: The answer was here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9516172/structuremap-configuration-for-di-with-asp-net-mvc-linq2sql-combo. NEVER would have figured this out myself, that's what's so great about the Internet in general and SO in particular.